# Android - Split the paragraphs in a string

Tags: android

I have a long string which holds the tags p /p for paragraphs. This is html string to be placed in web view.

I need to split the paragraphs into two and assign each one to a string.
Example:

```
String A:

<p> I have an orange <\p>
<p> I have an apple <\p>
<p> I have a banana <\p>
<p> I have a fruit <\p>
<p> I love to go bike riding<\p>
<p> Hello how are you <\p>

Now I need to split the paragraphs into 2 and assign to 2 different strings:

String B should have:
<p> I have an orange <\p>
<p> I have an apple <\p>
<p> I have a banana <\p>

String C should have:

<p> I have a fruit <\p>
<p> I love to go bike riding<\p>
<p> Hello how are you <\p>
```

how can I achieve it?

Comment: You mean `</p>`. Put a marker before the string **split**, such as "§" or the like. Then simply use the **split** function on A, using "§" as separator - in order to return an array of two strings. At position 0, you have B. At position 1, you have C.

Comment: will split return me the paragraphs?? and what is "§"??

Comment: It will return an array of two strings. At position 0, you have B. At position 1, you have C. Just extract these strings from the array.

Comment: will the first string end with </p>

Comment: if you use <\p> it will contain <\p>, so first you'd have to replace "<\p>" with "</p>".

Comment: "§" just to say a separator character - you can use "^", if you like it better. Just it must be a character that you don't use in regular text or in HTML tags

Comment: so I have give A.spilt("<\p>");??? where A is the string

Comment: NO. See my answer where to add the split character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code. Note where I added the **§** character in strA, in order to split the string:

```
final String strA = "<p> I have an orange </p><p> I have an apple </p><p> I have a banana </p>§<p> I have a fruit </p><p> I love to go bike riding</p><p> Hello how are you </p>";
final String arr[] = strA.split("§");
final String strB = arr[0]; // Contains: "<p> I have an orange </p><p> I have an apple </p><p> I have a banana </p>"
final String strC = arr[1]; // Contains: "<p> I have a fruit </p><p> I love to go bike riding</p><p> Hello how are you </p>"
```

Comment: I am getting index ou of bounds exception saying index is 1

Comment: Show me the code. I think you didn't copy my code exactly. If it says that the length is 0 and index is 1, it didn't split correctly. This is due to: `it doesn't find the split character in the full string`.

Comment: final String arr[] = articleBody.split("§");
    firstString = arr[0]; 
    nextString = arr[1];

Comment: But did you add the "§" character to `articleBody`? It won't split if it doesn't find the split character in the origin string.

Comment: No I don't have that character in the string. it has <p> and </p>

Comment: That's why. You must add the split character or it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I just assume you mean `</p>` instead of `<\p>` as the closing tag.

Assuming you always have this structure, with `<p>...</p>` following `<p>...</p>` and nothing inbetween, you can just do this:

```
String A = "<p> I have an orange </p>"
    + "<p> I have an apple </p>"
    + "<p> I have a banana </p>"
    + "<p> I have a fruit </p>"
    + "<p> I love to go bike riding</p>"
    + "<p> Hello how are you </p>";

String[] paragraphs = A.split("</p>");
final int halfParagraphs = (int) Math.ceil((double) paragraphs.length / 2);

StringBuilder bBuilder = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder cBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for(int idxB = 0; idxB < halfParagraphs; idxB++) {
    int idxC = idxB + halfParagraphs;
    // split removes the separator, so we need to append it again
    bBuilder.append(paragraphs[idxB]).append("</p>");
    if (paragraphs.length > idxC) {
        cBuilder.append(paragraphs[idxC]).append("</p>");
    }
}
String B = bBuilder.toString();
String C = cBuilder.toString();
```

I also assumed you want String B to hold more values if the number cannot be evenly distributed. This is certainly not the cleanest solution, but it works without adding an extra character in the Text.

Comment: sample string : <div style="font-size:21;color:rgba(0,0,0,1.0);">Mar 24, 2014<p><p>           <p>They say 2014 will be a rebuilding year for the Phillies.</p><p><p>Same for Aramark, which handles the food at Citizens Bank Park.</p><p><p>For its 11th season at the ballpark, Aramark rebuilt many kitchens. The new equipment will allow for new food options and perhaps add some speed this season.</p><p><p>At least part of the new lineup - to be announced Monday, March 24 - is smokin'.</p><p><p>Kevin Tedesco, Aramark's general manager, and Jeremy Campbell, its director of concessions </p></div>

Comment: Well if you have a full-blown HTML String, you should probably use an HTML/XML parser instead of writing your own stuff.

Comment: Take a look at the list here and see if anything works for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2188513/1966616